# Laravel: How can I return more data from a custom UserProvider?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have successfully created a [custom user provider](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) and have implemented a user interface.

I am trying to save the user object to my local Postgres database that is returned from a third party backend.

Here is what my `retrieveByCredentials` method looks like:

```
// MyCustomUserProvider.php

public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials) {
    if (empty($credentials)) {
        return null;
    }


    try {
        $response = Http::asForm()
            ->retry(3, 100)
            ->timeout(5)
            ->post('https://my-custom-auth-endpoint', $credentials)
            ->json();

            if ($response) {
                $user = User::firstOrNew([
                    'foo' => $response['foo'],
                ]);

                $user->save();

                return $user;
            }
    } catch (RequestException $e) {
        Log::info('-----------------------------------------------------------');
        Log::info(print_r($e->getMessage(), true));
        Log::info('-----------------------------------------------------------');

        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}

...

public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials): bool {
        return strtoupper($user->foo) === strtoupper($credentials['foo']);
}
```

So far, everything is working great. I am getting the correct values/booleans for each required method. However, I need to be able to return additional info to my controller than just a boolean value. For example, if a user's password has expired, this information is coming from my 3rd party database. So far, it looks like returning the `user` results in a `true` or `false` response in my `LoginController`. If I get `false` back from my `CustomProvider` I can set a flash message of, "Invalid Credentials". But that may not always be the appropriate error.

Here is how I am calling the `CustomUserProvider`:

```
// LoginController.php

$authenticated = Auth::guard('foo')
    ->attempt([
        'userid' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ]);


// $authenticated is the response from CustomUserProvider.
dd($authenticated) // true or false.
```

It is understood that in my provider I just want to authenticate the user. How can I return the authenticated user back to the controller? Additionally, how can I return the error back to the controller so I can display a proper error message?

Answer (score 0):

The function `Auth::guard('foo')->attempt([])` will also return a boolean to tell user if the authentication is successful or not. If you want to get the auth user, just return `Auth::user()` after the calling that function, like `return response()->json(Auth::user())`